# How to add entry to fish shell history?

Tags: fish

In my fish function, I'm evaluating constructed commandline via
`eval (commandline)`, specifically - I'm looking for some file name from fzf, and then analyze if commandline was prepended with `vim`. If it was - instead of returning `vim filename` to press enter afterwards, I just evaluate it, as I showed before.

The thing is that if I evaluate it, instead of pressing enter manually, it is not going to history - e.g. I can not see it as previous command by pressing up.

I tried `set -x history (commandline) $history` after eval, but it shows me an error `set: Tried to change the read-only variable “history”`

Is there a way to manually add custom string (in my case commandline buffer) to history? thx.

Answer (score 10):

`history --merge` does not merge history in chronological order [#2312](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2312). So even if we manually add the command to `~/.config/fish/fish_history` we will no be able to simply press up to see it (although you will get to it eventually if you press up enough).

To get around this we can make a copy of `fish_history` then call `builtin history --clear` which will clear both fish's internal history and the history file. We then restore the history file from our copy, append our command  and call `history --merge` to merge the history file with the now empty internal history.

```
function evalh
    eval $argv

    # backup history file
    cp ~/.config/fish/fish_history /tmp/fish_history.tmp

    # clear internal history and history file (using builtin means we don't get a prompt)
    builtin history --clear

    # restore history file
    cp /tmp/fish_history.tmp ~/.config/fish/fish_history

    # append our command 
    echo "- cmd:" $argv >> ~/.config/fish/fish_history
    echo "  when:" (date "+%s") >> ~/.config/fish/fish_history

    # merge history file with (empty) internal history
    history --merge
end
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way to do this, hence why I've added a bounty to the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval`, you can use the `-f` option on `commandline` to inject readline functions---specifically, `execute`.

For example, I wrote a function `substitute` that performs an analogous action to bash's `^foo^bar` syntax:

```
function substitute
    set -l last $history[1]
    switch (count $argv)
        case 3
            if test $argv[3] = 'g'
                commandline (echo $last | sed "s/$argv[1]/$argv[2]/g")
                commandline -f execute
            else
                echo "Syntax: substitute <find> <replace> [g]"
            end
        case 2
            commandline (echo $last | sed "s/$argv[1]/$argv[2]/")
            commandline -f execute
        case '*'
            echo "Syntax: substitute <find> <replace> [g]"
    end
end
```

Which in my `config.fish` is aliased to `s`:

```
alias s substitute
```

Usage looks like this (manual presses of the Enter key are replaced with the ⏎ character):

```
~> echo hi hi hi⏎
hi hi hi
~> s hi bye⏎
~> echo bye hi hi
bye hi hi
~> s hi bye g⏎
~> echo bye bye bye
bye bye bye
```

Note that, though it can't be displayed here, the commandlines created by `substitute` in this fashion are not syntax-highlighted.

It is either a bug or a feature that the `s foo bar` lines appear in your history in this context as well. I consider it a feature, so have not bothered fixing it.

Comment: Just FYI, but this unfortunately won't work in fish 3.4+, as apparently using `commandline` interactively to modify the buffer in this fashion wasn't intended to ever work, and now no longer does: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8807

Comment: Oh no, that's heartbreaking---no wonder my much-used `s` has stopped working! Have you found a workaround? I saw your speculation about "eval+munge history file" on that github issue but it's not clear if you've actually gotten that working yet from the comment?

Comment: update -- this behavior is back with fish 3.5.0! https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8807#issuecomment-1145612829 https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#fish-3-5-0-released-june-16-2022